# During which maven's phase the jsp are put on the target?

Tags: java, maven, jsp, gruntjs, maven-war-plugin

I need to know during which phase of the maven cycle the jsp are put on the target directory, and by which process.

I use the [`grunt-maven-plugin`](https://github.com/allegro/grunt-maven-plugin) to do a transformation on my `.jsp` files (I generate the insert of the js scripts if you want to know).

Grunt duplicates the jsp file in a temp dir, do its job and put the updated jsp on the target/${project.build.name} directory.
(if I only launch grunt, I can check it's work)

My issue is that the updated file is overwritten by the original jsp who is moved on this same repository.

if I only launch grunt(I do  a `mvn compile`, who launch the grunt task), I can check my grunt work fine. But if I do a `mvn install`, the files are overwritten.

I think I can correct it by launching grunt after the original jsp are moved.

**Question**: Do you know during **which phase of the maven cycle** the jsp are put on the target directory?

My project is a webapp from the maven artifact webapp, by the way.

Comment: Your packaging is `war` ? And you are using maven-war-plugin i assume?

Comment: I package with war, but I've the issue with and without the maven-war-plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to know during which phase of the maven cycle the jsp are put on the target directory, and by which process.

During the `package` phase by the [Maven War Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin) and its [`war`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html) goal.

Having packaging `war`, a Maven build will **by default** invoke `war:war` (`war` of the Maven War Plugin) during the `package` phase, according to [default packaging bindings](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging). Hence, no need to specify it explicitly in your POM file.

The Maven War Plugin will

- Build the full webapp, by default under  `${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}`, as specified by its [`webappDirectory`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#webappDirectory) configuration entry
- Package it as `.war` file under `${project.build.directory}` by default, as specified by its [`outputDirectory`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#outputDirectory) configuration entry

---

> My issue is that the updated file is overwritten by the original jsp who is moved on this same repository.

In this case you are having a file conflict, same files (with different content) in the same target folder (`target/${project.build.name}` as you mentioned is the same as the default War Plugin outputDirectory above).

You could redirect your modified `.jsp` files under a different directory, say `target/grunt` and then configure the Maven War Plugin to also take resources from this directory. These additional resources will be added **after** the default ones and as such override them (in case of conflicts).

For instance, you could configure your POM file with the following addition:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <webResources>
            <resource>
                <!-- this is relative to the pom.xml directory -->
                <directory>target/grunt</directory>
            </resource>
        </webResources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The global configuration will be also applied to the default Maven War Plugin executed as part of the aforementioned bindings.

In the snippet above, we are saying to the Maven War Plugin to also include resources from the `target/grunt` folder. Any `.jsp` file present in that folder would then be added to the built webapp (as folder and `.war` file) and override the original `.jsp` files (as you actually wanted).